# Factor of a Mersenne number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Why is it true that if 7 divides 91 then $(2^7-1) $ divides $(2^{91}-1)$?

**1) $2^{91}-1$**

$7|91  \implies (2^7-1)|(2^{91}-1)$

$\implies 2^7-1$ is factor

**2) $2^{1001}-1$**

$7|1001  \implies (2^7-1)|(2^{1001}-1)$

$\implies 2^7-1$ is factor

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $a,b$ are distinct integers, $(a-b)\mid\left(p(a)-p(b)\right)$. In particular $(a^n-1)\mid (a^{nm}-1)$, which is trivial by polynomial division, too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We have $$2^{91}-1 = (2^7)^{13}-1 = (2^7-1)((2^7)^{12}+...+2^7+1)$$

More generally:

$$2^{ab}-1 = (2^a)^{b}-1 = (2^a-1)((2^a)^{b-1}+...+2^a+1)$$

so $2^a-1\mid 2^{ab}-1$

And we can replace $2$ with any other number.

Comment: Which proves that if `M = 2^p - 1` is a Mersenne prime, then `p` must be prime too. Example: `127 = 2^7 - 1` is prime, and so is `7`. `7 = 2^3 - 1` is prime, and so is `3 = 2^2 - 1`, and so is 2.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 34):

It may be illustrative to write the numbers out in binary.  I'll use $2^{21} - 1 = (2^7)^3 - 1$ instead of $2^{91} - 1$, since it's shorter:

$$\begin{aligned}
2^{21} - 1
&= \underbrace{111111111111111111111}_{21\text{ digits}}\,\vphantom1_2 \\
&= \underbrace{1111111}_{7\text{ digits}}\,\underbrace{1111111}_{7\text{ digits}}\,\underbrace{1111111}_{7\text{ digits}}\,\vphantom1_2 \\
&= 1111111_2 \times 100000010000001_2 \\
&= (2^7 - 1) \times (2^{14} + 2^7 + 1).
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Excellent argument and visualization. Thanks!

Comment: That is some great insight and excellent use of binary.