# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. If $b=ak$ for some $k \gt 0$ then $2^b − 1 = (2^a)^k − 1 = (2^a − 1)m$ for some $m$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I came across a homework question asking if this is true or false. After plugging in some numbers, this turned out to be true. May I know a proof or explanation for this? I sort of know this is related to congruence and GCD, but unsure of how to start.

Comment: Special case of the linked Factor Theorem: put $\, n = 2^a,\ m=1,\ r = k\ $ to get $\,2^a -1\mid (2^a)^k-1\ \ $

Comment: Here's a previous question on specific powers of 2 with some general answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626598/factor-of-a-mersenne-number

Answer (score -1):

By modular arithmetic:

Take $M_a:= 2^a-1$. Then $2^a \equiv 1 \bmod M_a$ and $2^b=(2^a)^k\equiv 1^k\equiv 1 \bmod M_a$

Thus $M_a$ divides $2^b{-}1$.

Comment: Note this argument can be easily generalized; $a^{\large b}{-}1$ divides $a^{\large bc}{-}1$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: Hi @BillDubuque - I think the OP might struggle to apply that generalized case to their question - is there a simpler dupe to link?

Comment: It's not much of a  "struggle" to substitute $\,n = 2^a,\ m=1.\ $ The arguments here are already given in the dupe (and hundreds of prior answers).

Comment: I see now you explained it in a comment on the main question, so that helps, good.